# how to upload database from localhost to server automatically?

Tags: php, mysql, database

My software database in MySQL in localhost and another database on server.
how to i synchronise loaclhost to server database?
i want to add function in my software when my PC connect to internet that time automatic data update in server database from localhost

Comment: Hi! Is the assumption correct that you're using MySQL or MariaDB?

Comment: i use MySQL(PHPMYADMIN) @JakobRunge

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Replication`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto.html)

> Replication enables data from one MySQL database server (the master)
>   to be replicated to one or more MySQL database servers (the slaves).
>
> Replication is asynchronous - slaves need not be connected permanently
>   to receive updates from the master. This means that updates can occur
>   over long-distance connections and even over temporary or intermittent
>   connections such as a dial-up service. Depending on the configuration,
>   you can replicate all databases, selected databases, or even selected
>   tables within a database.

Comment: @cipher Read the documentation.